# How do I store a list/array of classes in a Groovy variable?

Tags: groovy

I want to store a list/array of Java exception classes (e.g. NullPointerException, some custom exception classes, etc.) into a Groovy list/array, but I keep running into either casting problems or MissingPropertyException:

```
class Foo {
  Exception[] foo
  List bar

  def setFoo(Exception[] values) {
    this.foo = values
  }

  def setBar(List values) {
    this.bar = values
  }
}

f = Foo()
f.setFoo([NullPointerException.class])
f.setBar(Arrays.asList(NullPointerException.class))
```

But I can't seem to get it right. Any pointer is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changes to

```
class Foo {
    Class[] foo
    List bar

    def setFoo(Class[] values) {
        this.foo = values
    }

    def setBar(List values) {
        this.bar = values
    }


}
    def f = new Foo()
    f.setFoo([NullPointerException.class] as Class[])
    f.setBar(Arrays.asList(NullPointerException.class))
```

1. `foo` should be an array of `Class` rather than `Exception`. (`Exception` is the instance of Exception Class)
2. You need to explicitly cast list to Class array, which does the conversion from list to array for you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with just `def list = [UserClass1, UserClass2]`. In groovy, even `.class` not required.

You code should as below, isn't this simple?

```
class Foo {
  def bar
}

def f = new Foo(bar: [NullPointerException, RuntimeException])
assert f.bar instanceof List<Class>
assert (f.bar as Class[]) instanceof Class[]
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/3Rd9HV)</kbd>